# Como usar alturas diferentes para IMC em C?

Tags: c

No meu programa de calculo de IMC (em C), deve-se digitar a massa primeiro e a altura em seguida (de n pessoas). Gostaria de saber por que ele esta considerando as massas de forma correta porém está usando sempre a primeira altura para calcular.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)

{

    float massa, altura, IMC;

    float *b=NULL;

    int counter = 2;

    int i, j;

    float somacounter;

    int counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0, counter3 = 0, counter4 = 0, counter5 = 0, counter6 = 0, counter7 = 0;

    b=(float*) malloc(2 * sizeof(float));

    scanf("%f",&massa);
    scanf("%f",&altura);

    b[0]=massa;
    b[1]=altura;

    int flag = 1;

    while(flag)
    {
        scanf("%f",&massa);
        scanf("%f",&altura);

        if(massa == 0.00 && altura == 0.00)
        {
            flag = 0;
            continue;
        }

         counter = counter + 2;
         b = (float*) realloc (b , (counter) * sizeof(float));

        b[counter - 2] = massa;
        b[counter - 1] = altura;

    }

   for(i = 0 ; i < counter - 1 ; i++)

   {

    for(j = 1 ; j < counter - 2; j = i + 1)

            {

                IMC = b[i]/(b[j]*b[j]);
                i++;
                j = i + 1;

                if(IMC<17)
                {
                    printf("\nMuito abaixo do peso");
                    counter1++;
                    break;
                }
                if(IMC>=17 && IMC<=18.49)
                {
                    printf("\nAbaixo do peso");
                    counter2++;
                    break;
                }
                if(IMC>=18.5 && IMC<=24.99)
                {
                    printf("\nPeso Normal");
                    counter3++;
                    break;
                }
                if(IMC>=25 && IMC<=29.99)
                {
                    printf("\nAcima do peso");
                    counter4++;
                    break;
                }
                if(IMC>=30 && IMC<=34.99)
                {
                    printf("\nObesidade I");
                    counter5++;
                    break;
                }
                if(IMC>=35 && IMC<=39.99)
                {
                    printf("\nObesidade II (severa)");
                    counter6++;
                    break;
                }
                if(IMC>=40)
                {
                    printf("\nObesidade III (Morbida)");
                    counter7++;
                    break;
                }

            }
   }

               somacounter = counter1+counter2+counter3+counter4+counter5+counter6+counter7;

               printf("\n\nMuito abaixo do peso: %d (%.2f )", counter1, counter1/somacounter * 100);
               printf("\nAbaixo do peso: %d (%.2f )", counter2, counter2/somacounter * 100);
               printf("\nPeso normal: %d (%.2f )", counter3, counter3/somacounter * 100);
               printf("\nAcima do peso: %d (%.2f )", counter4, counter4/somacounter * 100);
               printf("\nObesidade I: %d (%.2f )", counter5, counter5/somacounter * 100);
               printf("\nObesidade II (severa): %d (%.2f )", counter6, counter6/somacounter * 100);
               printf("\nObesidade III (morbida): %d (%.2f )", counter7, counter7/somacounter * 100);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Está um pouco difícil entender o que o seu programa está fazendo. O nome das suas variáveis está bem confuso (counter7, "b", "flag"), tem várias variáveis redundantes ("soma" e "altura", "flag"+continue ao invés de dar break...), as massas e alturas estão misturadas todas no mesmo vetor...  Você acha que você consegue produzir uma versão mais simples do seu programa que ainda reproduza o seu erro? Se bobear, durante o processo de simplificação você até acha o erro.  Também não custa nada botar uns printfs no meio do código pra ver o que está acontecendo :)

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que teu erro venha do **break** dentro dos *ifs*, que quebra o *for* da variavel **j** (até por isso nao é recomendado a utilização de quebras de loops).

Troque ele por **else if** na próxima condição.

```
        if(IMC<17)
        {
            printf("\nMuito abaixo do peso");
            counter1++;
        }
        else if(IMC>=17 && IMC<=18.49)
        {
            printf("\nAbaixo do peso");
            counter2++;
        }
        else if(IMC>18.49 && IMC<=24.99)
        {
            printf("\nPeso Normal");
            counter3++;
        }
```

Outro ponto, tente nomear as variáveis com algo que vc possa compreender sem precisar achar a funcao dela no código. Por exemplo, ao invés de counter1, counter2..., troque-os por contadorAbaixo, contadorNormal, contadorObeso...